# Why does Java complain about a non-initialized variable even though every possible route leading to it's initialization has been handled?

Tags: java, null, switch-statement

Consider this:

```
class BlackMage {
    public void castSpell(SPELL_TYPE spellType) {
        Spell spell;

        if (spellType == null)
            return;

        switch(spellType) {
            case FIRE:
                spell = new Fire();
                break;
            case BLIZZARD:
                spell = new Blizzard();
                break;
            case THUNDER:
                spell = new Thunder();
                break;
        }

        // use spell
    }

    enum SPELL_TYPE {
        FIRE,
        BLIZZARD,
        THUNDER
    }
}
```

Unless I add a `default` block to the `switch` and initialize spell there, the compiler will complain about spell not being initialized. I don't understand why, since we handled all 3 possibilities.

Comment: You said you have 3 case, but compiler do not sure about that, who knows you will pass the value out of 3 case or not. If for some reason you but a value out of 3 case in here then the `spell` is not initialized

Comment: because java enum switch is not exhaustive

Comment: @user2478398 Even if I treat null it will still complain. See edit.

Comment: @luk2302 Not being exhaustive means the compiler won't enforce handling every enum value. But since I handled every possible enum value, this should work.

Comment: Suppose your enum is in a library called `a.jar` and this code is in `b.jar`. The creators of `a.jar` publish a new version with a new enum value. Since `b.jar` won't be recompiled, now we have an uninitialized variable case, which should never be allowed.

Comment: It obviously means that you need to treat the case where your variable is not any of your cases. Might not possible, because you have a case for every enum item, but the compiler won't check for that.

Comment: @MS Prima Vista: yes, but they're handled differently. In the same way if you do 'if (x) else if (!x)' you'll still get a complaint if you don't have a final else or something outside of the conditional. One reason being if this code is run against a later version of 'SPELL_TYPE' (which has new spells added), you wouldn't define any return for these new values.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Hmm that makes sense.

Comment: Side note: enums should be named like any other type, e.g. `SpellType`.

Comment: In general, switching on an enum is somewhat of an antipattern. Consider defining an abstract method to create the `Spell` instance, with each enum instance implementing it appropriately.

Comment: Reopening because this is about an enum switch covering all possibilities, not an int which could be any value.

Comment: @shmosel I don't know what was on my mind when I wrote that enum name.

Comment: @shmosel It doesn't matter if you switch over an enum or an int, OP needs a `default` case and the answer tells him that.

Comment: @Tom OP is obviously aware of that. The question was *why*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't go to the level of checking how many values your enumeration has.

Your switch doesn't have a default case, that will remove the error. Either replace the last case with default, or simply add an additional default block which assigns any random value; you know it will never evaluate but the compiler doesn't.